# gpg: No keyserver available

Tags: gnupg, gpg-agent

on my server i try to get the keys and execute the command

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1E9377A2BA9EF27F
```

but I get that the server is not available

```
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No keyserver available
```

but when i do the same on my local machine everything works fine.the key is imported.
help me pls
dns is the same on the server and on my local computer.
difference in versions of gpg and dirmngr on local 2.2.12 on server 2.2.4
Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it worked for me

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 34893610CEAA9512
```

you can use script

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a keyservers=(
    "hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80"
    "keyserver.ubuntu.com"
    "ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net"
    "hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80"
    "p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net"
    "hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80"
    "pgp.mit.edu"
    "hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80"
)

keys=$(apt update 2>&1 | grep -o '[0-9A-Z]\{16\}$')

for key in $keys; do
    for server in "${keyservers[@]}"; do
        echo "Fetching GPG key ${key} from ${server}"
        apt-key adv --keyserver $server --keyserver-options timeout=10 --recv-keys ${key}
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "Key '${key}' successful added from server '${server}'"
            break
        else
            echo "Failed add key '${key}' from server '${server}'. Try another server"
            continue
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: In my case, I set the keys variable like this:  `keys=$(apt update 2>&1 |grep "GPG error" | awk '{ print $13 }')`

The ERROR msg look like this: 
```bash 
W: GPG error: https://my.server.domain/artifactory/Hashicorp-apt-repo-key jammy InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: REVKEYSIG DA418C88A3219F7B HashiCorp Security (HashiCorp Package Signing) <security+packaging@hashicorp.com>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have network access issue or environment issue.
This command works fine for me.
GPG and Ubuntu versions, which I'm using:

```
gpg --version | head -2; lsb_release -d
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.19
libgcrypt 1.8.5
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
```

Try to access **keyserver.ubuntu.com** via **curl** and see what happens

```
curl http://keyserver.ubuntu.com | & grep description
      <meta name="description" content="OpenPGP Keyserver">
```

Answer (score -1):

just disconnect your wifi and then again connect.
It worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).